# Xbinkeys does not work with mode_switch

Tags: xmodmap, xbindkeys

I'm trying to use `xbindkeys` with an event that is produced with `mode_switch + <key>`, but `xbindkeys` is triggered with only the `<key>` instead of the combination of it with the `mode_switch`.

I'm using `xmodmap` to map the `mode_switch` to right alt:

```bsh
keycode 108 = Mode_switch Mode_switch Mode_switch Mode_switch
```

When `xbindkeys` process is **not** running, I can see the expected events with `xev`, for the `<key>` alone and for the combination of `mode_switch + <key>`.

But when `xbindkeys` **is** running, it is triggering the code attached to it on the `<key>` alone, instead of the combination, which overrides what the key does originally.

For example, if I bind `Pointer_Button5` to the letter `n` with:

```bsh
keysym n = n N Pointer_Button5
```

without `xbindkeys` I can see `n` alone and `Pointer_Button5` when using `mode_switch + n` in `xev`, but with `xbindkeys` running, I can no longer use the `n` key, it instead is triggering the script attached to it.

It seems to be the same for other keys and events as well, not only `Pointer_Button5` or the letter `n`.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to update the used keyboard mapping (language/keyboard-model) to add the "alt" key that you are emulating... xmodmap wont be required after that.

This can be done by editing the keyboard (language) file under `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet` or `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/fr` if you are using french keybpard (location may differ)

Make sure the proper key is working then restart xbindkeys.

(Not sure 100% but this may help, also this solution will be erased with package updates, so backup your changes)

Comment: I'm mapping `Alt_R` to produce `Mode_switch` which is then used as a layout switch for combination with other keys. I was hoping of solving it with `xmodmap` since it seems much simpler, but I'll give it a try. Maybe similar to this issue, some programs e.g. `unity-editor` and `freemind` treat this bind of `Mode_switch` +hjkl arrows differently than real arrows. In `xev` the difference is the state, for `Mode_switch + hjkl (or any other keys) it is `0x2000` and for arrows it is `0x0`.

Comment: I guess that you have some trouble because the mapped key is emulated, i know that editing the keyboard mapping as i suggested is done at a lower level and thus may help... had a similar issue and ended-up doing that to fully remap the key